# Add an Ionic page into another Ionic Page - Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a page which I use as a normal page within an Ionic 4 app, but I also need to reuse it else where in the app, within another page, so as to stop duplication of code.

My current approach was to follow the approach taken for a normal directive and add the selector to the page I wish to put the page within:

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

Then add the child page module import into the parent page module:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ComponentsModule,
    ChildPageModule,
  ],
  declarations: [ParentPage]
})
export class ParentPageModule {}
```

However I am then hit with the error:

```
ChildPage is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
```

Which of course makes sense, because it is a main page and now a component page.

I tried moving the import into the app module, tried adding the page into the declarations of the parent page module, but all fail to solve the issue.

Any ideas on how to get a page within a page in Ionic 4/Angular 6

Comment: Try to keep the declaration only in the page module itself and call with lazy loading when you want to use it as component. To call with lazy loading only pass the page name with quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

You should create a component for the Childpage.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-childpage',
  templateUrl: './childpage.component.html'
})

export class ChildpageComponent {

}
```

Then create a `components.module.ts` and do:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChildpageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    ChildpageComponent
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {}
```

Now you can use the `<app-childpage></app-childpage>` selector in your other pages by importing the `ComponentsModule` into their respective Modules